# What is the meaning of mean of a probability distribution table?

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose there is a random variable X which takes the values as $X = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}$. Each number in this set denotes the total number of wins (head) in a coin game where an unbiased coin is tossed **$4$** times. Then $$P(X_i) = (\frac{1}{2})^4, 4*(\frac{1}{2})^4, 6*(\frac{1}{2})^4, 4*(\frac{1}{2})^4, (\frac{1}{2})^4$$

respectively for each $X_i$. Now the mean of this probability distribution table comes out to be $$\sum{P_iX_i} = 2$$

Now my question is, what is the meaning of the above value? Like someone comes to me describes the above same experiment and tells me hey the mean is $2$, what am I supposed to conclude from this?

Comment: The mean is actually $2$. And an interpretation is, if you play the game many times, the average of your scores will tend to $2$.

Comment: @Milten how did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation is incorrect; the mean is 2.

Comment: Thanks, edited the post